# Ionic 1: Link not working in popup content

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-popup

I working with ionic pop-up where inside the popup content, I want a clickable link. The problem is that the link that I created is not working. Can't click them. My code is as follows:

```
var mypopup = $ionicPopup.show({
   template: '<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>',
   buttons: [{
       text: 'Ok'
   }]
})
```

Is there any way I can enable a user to click that link and go to Google?

Many thanks!

Comment: That clickable with ionic serve you are getting trouble in real device?

Comment: @PareshGami yes. Unable to click on a real device. Any solution?

Comment: You need to open in-app-browser when link is clicked?

Comment: @PareshGami I have no problem using in-app-browser on a page but not in a pop-up. Got other tips?

Comment: Working for me. But might be issue with button keyword its buttons not button

Comment: @PareshGami do you mean instead of using `<a>`, I should use `<button>`?

Comment: Check this http://keepnote.cc/YellowGogi

Comment: @PareshGami ops... that's my bad. Unfortunately, the link still not working. Anyway, thanks for your assistant!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `target="_blank"` property inside anchor tag and it will work perfectly fine. It will launch browser.

Your **current** code:

`template: '<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>',`

**Change to**:

```
template: '<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>',
```

Here is **working codepen snippet**:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rvaONv?editors=1010